# How to declare a property with decimal(19,4)

Tags: c#, decimal

want to declare a decimal property with decimal(8,4).
but the default of C# is decimal(18,2).

```
    public class GroupItems
    {

        public GroupItems()
        {


        }

        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemAmount { get; set; }
        public double ItemQty { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: C#  `decimal` / .NET `System.Decimal` *doesn't work like that* (i.e. precision specific to the member). It just stores the value given...

Comment: Which one? (19,4) as in the title or (8,4) as in the question?

Comment: What do you mean and from where did you get the default (18,2) part ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly. You can use the set method to implement this behavior.

```
    private decimal _myProperty;

    public decimal MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set {
            if (value <= 99999999) //for 8 
            {
                _myProperty = Math.Round(value,4);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this , for the things you want to achieve

```
  decimal _ItemPrice; 
  public decimal ItemPrice 
  { get
    { return Math.Round(_ItemPrice, 2) } 
    set
    { _ItemPrice = value;}
  }
```

You need to make change in the get and set of your property as in above code..

Answer (score -1):

Precision of .net decimal is "28-29 significant digits" which is more than enough for this case. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)